# How do I set up both option frame=tb and multicols=2 in lstings environment, so that they work well at the same time

Tags: multicol, code, frame

My minimal example is here：

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{multicol}

\lstdefinelanguage{Cpp}{
    keywords={auto, double, int, struct, break, else, long,
    switch, case, enum, register, typedef, char, extern,
    return, union, continue, for, signed, void, do, if, static,
    while, default, goto, sizeof, volatile, const, float, short, unsigned, NULL, \#include, \#define},
    sensitive=true,
    alsoletter = {\#},
    comment=[l]{//},
    morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/},
    morestring=[b]',
    morestring=[b]"
}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
% Basic design
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\linespread{1}\small,
  frame=t,
    multicols=2,
%framesep=5pt,
    framerule=.5pt,
    rulecolor=\color{violet},
    abovecaptionskip=0pt,
    belowcaptionskip=5pt,
% Code design
    keywordstyle=\color{codecolorkeywords},
    commentstyle=\color{codecolorcomments},
    stringstyle=\color{codecolorstrings},
    numberstyle=\small\color{gray},
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    breaklines=true,
    captionpos=t,
    keepspaces=true,
% Line numbers
    numbers=left,
    numbersep=2pt,
    xleftmargin=.5em,
    stepnumber=1,
    firstnumber=1,
    numberfirstline=true,
% Code
    tabsize=4,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    breaklines=true,
}
\lstset{style=mystyle}

\begin{document}
    \lstset{language=Cpp}

    \begin{lstlisting}[frame=tb, caption={caption}]
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdbool.h>

    void swap(int *q, int a, int b) {
        int tmp = q[a];
        q[a] = q[b];
        q[b] = tmp;
    }

    void quick_sort(int *q, int l, int r)
        {
        if (l >= r) {
            return;
        }
        int x = q[(l + r) >> 1];
        int i = l - 1;
        int j = r + 1;
        while (i < j) {
            do i++; while (q[i] < x);
            do j--; while (q[j] > x);
            if (i < j) {
                swap(q, i, j);
            }
        }
        quick_sort(q, l, j);
        quick_sort(q, j + 1, r);
    }
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

The above code will generate it like below.
[image: generated pdf like that]

But I would like to get the frame line across multicols from LHS to RHS instead of the half of text width. And the second column of the multicols environment will move down to avoid overlap with the extended frame line.

Any answer will be helpful. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `multicols` environment is added to the `Init` and `DeInit` hooks in `listings`. The caption and frame is added to the same hooks, but after the multicol code, so the caption and frame end up inside of the columns.

You can move the multicol code to the `InitVars` and `ExitVars` hooks instead, which are executed just after `Init` and before `DeInit`, respectively. See the listings [Developer's guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings-devel.pdf) for the exact order of all hooks.

A quick way of implementing this is to remove the `multicols` key from the `lstset` options and instead hardcode the number of columns in the hook.

Note that there was probably a reason why multicols was in Init and DeInit, and before the caption, so this modification may cause problems at some point.

One problem pointed out by the OP is that `\lstinline` fragments are now also multicolumn. A quick fix is to introduce a new if and make the multicolumns conditional on this if. This requires an explicit `\applymulticoltrue` statement before code that you want to be in two columns and a `\applymulticolfalse` statement before inline code (or a single column regular listing). This is a switch, so you need to set it only once and then it will be applied to all following listings until you change the value.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{multicol}
\colorlet{codecolorkeywords}{black}
\colorlet{codecolorcomments}{black}
\colorlet{codecolorstrings}{black}
\lstdefinelanguage{Cpp}{
    keywords={auto, double, int, struct, break, else, long,
    switch, case, enum, register, typedef, char, extern,
    return, union, continue, for, signed, void, do, if, static,
    while, default, goto, sizeof, volatile, const, float, short, unsigned, NULL, \#include, \#define},
    sensitive=true,
    alsoletter = {\#},
    comment=[l]{//},
    morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/},
    morestring=[b]',
    morestring=[b]"
}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
% Basic design
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\linespread{1}\small,
  frame=t,
    %multicols=2,
%framesep=5pt,
    framerule=.5pt,
    rulecolor=\color{violet},
    abovecaptionskip=0pt,
    belowcaptionskip=5pt,
% Code design
    keywordstyle=\color{codecolorkeywords},
    commentstyle=\color{codecolorcomments},
    stringstyle=\color{codecolorstrings},
    numberstyle=\small\color{gray},
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    breaklines=true,
    captionpos=t,
    keepspaces=true,
% Line numbers
    numbers=left,
    numbersep=2pt,
    xleftmargin=.5em,
    stepnumber=1,
    firstnumber=1,
    numberfirstline=true,
% Code
    tabsize=4,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    breaklines=true,
}
\lstset{style=mystyle}
\newif\ifapplymulticol
\makeatletter
\lst@AddToHook{InitVars}{\ifapplymulticol\edef\lst@next{\noexpand\multicols{2}}\expandafter\lst@next\fi}
\lst@AddToHook{ExitVars}{\ifapplymulticol\def\lst@next{\global\let\@checkend\@gobble
                      \endmulticols
                      \global\let\@checkend\lst@@checkend}
        \expandafter\lst@next\fi}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
    \lstset{language=Cpp}
    \applymulticoltrue
    \begin{lstlisting}[frame=tb, caption={caption}]
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdbool.h>

    void swap(int *q, int a, int b) {
        int tmp = q[a];
        q[a] = q[b];
        q[b] = tmp;
    }

    void quick_sort(int *q, int l, int r)
        {
        if (l >= r) {
            return;
        }
        int x = q[(l + r) >> 1];
        int i = l - 1;
        int j = r + 1;
        while (i < j) {
            do i++; while (q[i] < x);
            do j--; while (q[j] > x);
            if (i < j) {
                swap(q, i, j);
            }
        }
        quick_sort(q, l, j);
        quick_sort(q, j + 1, r);
    }
    \end{lstlisting}

\applymulticolfalse
Some text with inline listing \lstinline{i = i + 1;} in a sentence

Some text with inline listing \lstinline{do i++; while (q[i] < x); do j--; while (q[j] > x);} in a longer sentence

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. It really makes my life easier. It does have a problem, which causes the `\lstinline{}` style to two columns, which is unacceptable. I decided to use `newtcblisting` to get similar effects -- two columns with frame borders around the code. But I can't make the frame just top and bottom.

Comment: @wuxiaoqiang I added a quick fix for the `\lstinline` issue.

Comment: Wow, very impressive. It works properly.

Comment: Note that it would be easier to introduce a new option key instead of a separate conditional, or even to rewrite the handling of the original `multicols` key, but this was less effort :) you could send an e-mail to the maintainer Jobst Hoffmann (j.hoffmann(at)fh-aachen.de) to propose this change with a proper implementation.